# UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'Profile' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, html, django

How to solve this issue of `UnboundLocalError at /profile/
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment`. I am seeing it to be okay? When I remove `Payment_method` dropdown menu,, it works but why it is not working with dropdown menu?

**models.py**

```
Paymet_choices = (
    ('easypaisa','EasyPaisa Number'),
    ('jazzcash', 'Jazzcash Number'),
)
class Profile(models.Model):
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=Paymet_choices)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields  = ['image','Payment_method','Detail']
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

        context = {
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: If the method is POST but the form is not valid you never define context. You only define it in the else when the method is GET

Comment: You only define a variable `context` in the `else` block.

Comment: Okay great but how to deal with this ```CharField``` which is giving me error ```Ensure this value has at most 6 characters (it has 9) in form field```? Although I increased number of alphabets.

Comment: Find the CharField in your code that has a limit of 6 characters and there is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error means you are using `context` variable before you assign it.

there's 2 problem.
first, your form is invalid on this line:
`if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():`
so, it will continue execute the next lines (which means outside the outer `else` statement):
`return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)`
while you haven't assign the value for `context` variable.

second problem, to solve that errors, check your indentation.

```
        context = {
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

it supposed to be

```
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

it will solve that error,
so now, back to the first problem, your form is invalid.
We don't know why until you see the errors using [`form.errors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors).
add this anywhere in your `users/profile.html` template to check the errors
`{{ form.non_field_errors }}`

Comment: The second problem arised that how to deal with ```CharField``` because whenever I load the form it give message that ```Ensure this value has at most 6 characters (it has 9) in form field```

Comment: it means you set maximum length for that field is 6. if you want to increase its number from your Models, you should do [`Migrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/) after you change it.

Comment: nice to hear that, can you upvote it too if it is useful for you? thanks :D